# Linking error while bulding code with WASM

Tags: linker, webassembly

I am building C++ code using wasm(emsdk version 3.1.3) and cmake(3.15.5) and am getting the following error: -

`wasm-ld: error: /Users/...somePath.../boost/boost_thread/libboost_thread.a(thread.obj): undefined symbol: __wasm_lpad_context`

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Something of a guess -- is it possible you ran the link command via `emcc` instead of `em++`?

Comment: @NickLewycky my last lines of error are
`wasm-ld: error: /Users/...somePath.../boost/boost/boost_thread/libboost_thread.a(thread.obj): undefined symbol: __wasm_lpad_context

wasm-ld: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use -error-limit=0 to see all errors)

em++: error: '/Users/harjsing/Code/emsdk/emsdk/upstream/bin/wasm-ld @/var/folders/fl/cd37p9vx07d33jdvtww9cq_m0000gn/T/emscripten_2y3wu1x1.rsp.utf-8' failed (returned 1)`
It seems that em++ is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the answer. You need to add the flag `-fwasm-exceptions` to your list of compiler and linker flags.